# Is there any option in Firebase/Firestore for custom username and password authentication in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I searched a lot on the net but couldn't find a solution to creating a login app which validates username and password from Firestore/Firebase, I don't need the providers already mentioned in the Firebase such as Google-sign in, email, phone etc.
Do I need to create my own Database and write the authentication code myself or Firebase has an option for this.

Edit: I want to have a custom username and password to be authenticated from the database. Is there any option for this in Firebase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)?

Comment: No, not like that, suppose I have given each user a specific custom username, e.g, usr1, and a password pass1, there are many users so how can a validate the correct username and password in Firebase, thhe options provide there are without the server side code. This pertains to Flutter app development creating a login page.

Comment: You don't need server-side code for this, you just set up email/password authentication in your Firebase console and follow that guide for client-side code (using `signInWithEmailAndPassword`).  You can also create user accounts in the Firebase console or let users register.

Comment: okay, thank you for the help.